# Diagnosing laptop charging issues

Tags: laptop, battery, power, charging

My HP dv6000 laptop will not run on battery power. It will only run while plugged into the wall. I have already replaced the battery, but it still will not operate on battery power.

The problem began slowly. The original battery's life got shorter and shorter, until eventually it would only last ~45 seconds before going into hibernation. Finally, the battery would not work at all, so I threw it out and just used it without a battery. I bought a replacement recently.... but the problem persists.

When I connect the new battery to the system, the "charging" light turns on for about 30 seconds, then goes dark.

I'm assuming there's something wrong with the internal charging circuitry? If this is the case, how would I go about fixing this, short of buying a new motherboard?

If anyone could give me some assistance in confirming/rejecting my diagnosis I'd be very appreciative! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Unless you are **very** skilled at electronics and laptop assembly/disassembly there is not much else to do than have it sent in for repairs. And that is almost never worth the cost.

Comment: I've disassembled and reassembled quite a few laptops before, and I'm not afraid to swap the motherboard myself. I just don't have any experience with troubleshooting this issue, and want to be sure that the motherboard is the problem before I do anything crazy. And of course, if there's a piece I can solder onto the motherboard, that would save me from having to buy a new one!